# UIImage Not Splitting Properly

Tags: ios, uiimage, cgimageref

I am trying to split a `UIImage` in half horizontally, keeping the original width of the image, but the returned image is the top left corner of the original.

```
CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;

CGImageRef topR = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(imageRef, CGRectMake(0, 0,  image.size.width, image.size.height/2.0));
UIImage *topImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:topR];
CGImageRelease(topR);
```

When I set the rect to (0,0, 1000, image.size.height/2) it returns the full width of the image. I've printed `image.size.width` and it returns the correct width but createImageInRect is returning the top corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `CGImageGetWidth` instead and now it works

```
 CGImageRef topR = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(imageRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGImageGetWidth(imageRef), CGImageGetHeight(imageRef)/2));
```